# Correcting the already Deleted question

Tags: discussion

What is the purpose behind having Moderators correcting my **already** Deleted Question ?

Answer (score 3):

It’s not correction but rollbacks of vandalism. If the post is deleted, there’s no need to also vandalise the post and remove its contents. Vandalism, regardless of post, will be rolled back. Continued vandalism will cause the post to be locked and bulk-vandalism is grounds for suspension. See [Self-Vandalism, what is correct action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209436/self-vandalism-what-is-correct-action) and [Is vandalism of own deleted posts tolerated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266974/is-vandalism-of-own-deleted-posts-tolerated/).

Comment: how can I vandalize my own post ? the answer given does not make sense since the OP changed the question, Only few can see it anyway, so what is your motivation of insisting in showing the wrong answer.

Comment: OK @grg SUSPEND me than if you call that Vandalism.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Please read the accepted answer to the second link in grg‘s answer. There isn‘t much more to say to this than that. If you want to have the policy changed, or even propose a feature allowing a user to purge their posts, please raise the topic on meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @nohillside we are on meta ! so what is a definition of vandalize ? I believe this  post clearly explains it https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267076/217966. Using that as guidance my post are not Vandalized.

Answer (score -3):

I think we have a problem what is a definition of Vandalism.

[image]
**the original Post**

[image]

**How is this a VANDALIZED post ??**

In Deleting my post without comment does not help me nor others, that is why I change it so to know why was it deleted. If you want to insist that is vandalize so be it.

Why don't you just **suspend** me so I can go and help people with they Mac problems somewhere else, without been bullied.

Comment: Removing the content of a post (be it fully, or partially, and/or with a comment) is considered vandalism. I would argue that in this specific case it would not even have been necessary to delete it because it actually proposed a valid answer to the question asked. Maybe the OP didn’t like it, but others for sure would have. And as has already been explained, modifying a deleted post which not a lot of people can see is kind of pointless to start with.

Comment: @nohillside  `However, for an *occasional* case of "wow, that was a stunningly stupid mistake I made there and I'm really embarrassed; can we please not show that casually to 10k users?", I don't see a problem with replacing a post with something like "Withdrawing because this was completely wrong".  The edit should explain the situation; don't just mash keys to produce garbage.  If you find yourself doing this a lot, though, you should instead consider slowing down and making sure your answers are sound before you post them.` = Edits allowed !

Comment: We are talking about quite a lot of your posts here, I don‘t see the value of dissecting each and every one of those you vandalized after deleting them. Just accept the rules please (or have them changed). And as I already said: The answer you mentioned above was perfectly fine, I would probably have upvoted it even though the OP wanted something else. You have enough rep to not having to worry about some downvoted now and then.

Comment: @nohillside I would call this behavior Harassment or even Bulling. Moderators are not gods and not without mistakes them self. Explain to me why even this post got 2 down votes (so far). You have a mounting problem here from Targeting to Harassment to Intimidation to even Bullying. A good moderator should focus on that not on modifying deleted posts. Yes I delete a lot and always try to modify and explain why was it deleted in first place.

Comment: Voting on Meta works differently, it‘s not about rep but rather about approval or disapproval of a statement/opinion voiced in an answer.

Comment: Being a mod has a lot to do with curating good content and with making sure the rules are the same for everybody. We routinely fix deleted posts from users, yours are not the only ones. If you think moderating should be done differently feel free to volunteer in the next election.

Comment: @nohillside I must insist you report me for Vandalizing as stated here https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3430/46541 to the Moderator team, and let them decide.